# Doing a Gaussian Integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory

When you integrate over p you get:

[image]

by using

[image]

What are the steps to this? Do you integrate by parts?.

Comment: This is spelled out explicitly in the appendix to the first chapter of Zee.

Comment: Also, you are NOT supplying proper context: the exponent with the $q$'s appears out of nowhere in your question, while it's there all along in Zee's book. Same for the factor $2\pi$.

Comment: I got this straight from Zee but he does not explain the intermediate steps.

Comment: You clearly didn't read Appendix 1.

Comment: It looks better if you show some effort...

Comment: Hi user34039. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gaussian integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx =\sqrt{\pi}$$
(which is not very hard to prove). Now you only need to do a substitution to bring it into this form.

Comment: I can do this already. My question is how to evaluate the problem I posted.

Comment: It is the exact same problem.

Comment: $\frac{i\delta t p^2}{2m}=x^2$ gets you the answer immediately.

Comment: How so? Sorry for my stubbornness, can you explain further?

Comment: In the book, it is already rewritten using your last equation, so the problem really is just a single substitution.

Comment: Where does the -im come in?

Comment: @user34039 it's $m/i = -im$

Comment: Just carry out the substitution I gave you... It gives the answer immediately

Comment: @user34039 Not to be condesending or anything, but i recommend you revisit the rules for variable substitutions in integrals. Because as Danu has pointed out numerous times, it is simply that. A substitution in the prototype Gaussian integral.

Comment: user34039, perhaps it is better you show some effort, and indicate where you got stuck. Other people could start from that place.

Comment: But how do you substitute that problem into a simple gaussian integral?

Comment: You try to force it into the form of the simple gaussian. This is achieved by simply doing what I told you to do.

Comment: Can you show working please?

Comment: $ \langle q_{j+1} | e^{-i \delta t (p^2/2m)} | q_j \rangle = \int \int dp dp' \langle q_{j+1} | p \rangle \langle p| e^{-i \delta t (p^2/2m)} | p' \rangle \langle p'| q_j \rangle  $ 
$ = \int \int dp dp' \frac{e^{-ipq_{j+1} }}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{-i\delta t p^2/2m} \delta(p-p') \frac{e^{ip'q_{j} }}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $
$ = \int dp \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-ipq_{j+1} } e^{-i\delta t p^2/2m} e^{ipq_j} $

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for all the silly questions. :-)

Comment: @user34039 this was exactly in the few lines above the formula's you posted in Zee's book...

Comment: I'm sorry but going over the steps, I still don't see how you obtained the answer to the question. Can you please clarify?