# Gaussian Integral by Substitution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wick-rotation

I am trying the derive a path integral representation. I understand this involves Gaussian integrals of the form: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\text dx=\sqrt\pi$$
However, I am trying to evaluate the same integral but where
$$\frac{i\, \delta t\, p^2}{2m}=x^2.$$
How do you substitute this into the original Gaussian? I tried integration by parts but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the exact integral you're having problems with? Might be I don't understand path integral very well, but from the information you provided, I see no reason why the result of the integral would be different.

Comment: I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is your integration variable? It would be really helpful, as namehere said, to show us the exact integral you are trying to evaluate.

Comment: What do you mean? It's the substitution for x

Comment: Same integral but where x equals idtp^2/2m

Comment: From what I understand of your problem, you are trying to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$, after substituting $\frac{i{\delta}p^2}{2m}=x^2$. The result would have no reason to be different, remaining $\sqrt{\pi}$ all along.

Comment: @user34039 It then appears $\sqrt{\pi}$ is your answer. Nothing mysterious at all.

Comment: It equals x^2 not x

Comment: @namehere what about the Jacobian?

Comment: @user34039 My bad. Corrected the comment. That has no bearing on the result though, its still $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: Please show working out.

Comment: @Hunter I'm not sure that matters at all. If you substituted $\frac{i{\delta}p^2}{2m}=x^2$ into the integral, you could do the substitution back to $x$, which would the same integral, for which the answer we all know to be $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: I want it specifically in terms of the substitution i gave.

Comment: @user34039 And so I did. user34039, I think you might be misunderstanding the status of variables within integral. You see, the $x$ within the integral is integrated over, so it is a 'bounded' variable or 'dummy' variable, acting only as a placeholder. It does not matter what its value is, as its values are defined by the limits of integration. You cannot meaningfully change the value of a dummy variable. Changing its value will not change the result of the expression.

Comment: I still dont get it

Comment: @user34039@Hunter Might be my previous comment (about Jacobians) was not well phrased. I mean even if you HAD to substitute the x-p relationship into the integral, to evaluate it, the simplest way would be to substitute back to using x, because we already know how to do that integral. So if you're say, summing ${\Sigma}_{x=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$. Notice that the values of $x$ has already been defined and is used in evaluating the expression. Substituting in $p$ would be superficial, like evaluating ${\Sigma}_{p=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{2m}{i{\delta}p^2}}$ CANNOT change the result.

Comment: The value of an expression cannot depend on a bounded variable. I strongly recommend you to perhaps read more on relevant mathematical foundational knowledge before approaching any physics topic.

Comment: @user34039 I'm sorry but it appears your mathematical background is simply insufficient to properly approach this topic. Substitutions in integrals should be mastered by taking a course in calculus before attempting to tackle this theory (which requires **considerably more difficult** mathematical techniques like complex contour integrals to understand it properly).

Answer (score 3):

You need a slightly more general form for the integral, and in particular you need a form that allows for a constant in front of the $x^2$ in the exponent. To do this, using the substitution $y=\sqrt{a}x$, you do
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a x^2}\text dx=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\frac{\text dy}{\sqrt{a}}=
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.
$$
You can then do your substitution, changing $x$ for $p$ and choosing an appropriate value of $a$.

Comment: Can you please answer in terms of my specific substitution.

Comment: No. I will not do your work for you. I can point out the way to answer it, but that's as far as I will go. If you need clearer answers you should start with clearer questions.

Answer (score 1):

You asked the exact same thing [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101257/doing-a-gaussian-integral) and seemed satified with the answers and comments. I suggest you have a look at [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). But to give you peace of mind, let's spell it out.
Assuming $a\in\mathbb{C}, a \neq 0$ and setting $y^2=ax^2$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}\frac{dx}{dy}dy=\sqrt{a}^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}dy =\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

**Edit**: As Emilio Pisanty pointed out, for purely imaginary $a$, the integral is know as the [Fresnel Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) and contrary to my former remark *does* indeed converge. The value can be conviniently calculated by means of complex calculus. But at the end of the day this procedure justifies the substitution in the Gaussian integral.

Comment: So how did Zee do it?

Comment: As it happens, for imaginary $a$ the integral is a [Fresnel integral]() that still converges (though it is not absolutely convergent).